# How to change attributes of a networkx / matplotlib graph drawing?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, jupyter-notebook

NetworkX includes [functions](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/drawing.html) for drawing a graph using [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/). This is an example using the great IPython Notebook (started with `ipython3 notebook --pylab inline`):

[image]

Nice, for a start. But how can I influence attributes of the drawing, like coloring, line width and labelling? I have not worked with matplotlib before.

Comment: http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/drawing.html - you want the `draw_networkx_edges` and `draw_networkx_nodes` functions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IPython is a great tool for finding out what functions (and objects) can do. If you type

```
[1]: import networkx as nx
[2]: nx.draw?
```

you see

> Definition:   nx.draw(G, pos=None, ax=None, hold=None, **kwds)
>
> ```
> **kwds: optional keywords
>    See networkx.draw_networkx() for a description of optional keywords.
> ```

And if you therefore type

```
[10]: nx.draw_networkx?
```

you will see

```
node_color: color string, or array of floats
edge_color: color string, or array of floats
width: float
   Line width of edges (default =1.0)
labels: dictionary
   Node labels in a dictionary keyed by node of text labels (default=None)
```

So, armed with this information, and a bit of experimentation, it is not hard to arrive at:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import string

G = nx.generators.erdos_renyi_graph(18, 0.2)
nx.draw(G,
        node_color = np.linspace(0,1,len(G.nodes())),
        edge_color = np.linspace(0,1,len(G.edges())),
        width = 3.0,
        labels = {n:l for n,l in zip(G.nodes(),string.ascii_uppercase)}
        )
plt.show()
```

which yields

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to experiment with that. I am especially interested in mapping edge weights to line widths.

Comment: To have variable line widths, I think you would need to call `nx.draw_networkx_edges` once for each width. See [here](http://networkx.lanl.gov/examples/drawing/weighted_graph.html) for an example. There they change the line style, but it shows where you could also change the width.

Comment: Great, that you did not only answer the question but explained how to obtain the answer.