# Change edge thickness based on weight

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

When using `draw_networkx_edges()` of networkx, is it possible to change the thickness of the edges based on their weight?

Here I am assuming weights are less than some known number, say, k.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`edges(data='weight')`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.edges.html#edges):

> Edges are returned as tuples with optional data in the order (node, neighbor, data).

That is, you can get an edge's data by `edge[2]` when specifying `data='weight'` (or `edge[2]['weight']` if calling `data=True` to get all data elements as a dict).

Here's an example:

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edge('A', 'B', weight=5)
g.add_edge('A', 'C', weight=15)
g.add_edge('B', 'C', weight=7)

pos = nx.spring_layout(g, seed=0)
nx.draw_networkx(g, pos)

for edge in g.edges(data='weight'):
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(g, pos, edgelist=[edge], width=edge[2])
```

[image: graph drawing]

Answer (score 1):

One way to do is to categorize edges as shown in [this example](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/examples/drawing/weighted_graph.html).

step 1: add weights to edges
step 2: categorize edgelist based on weight
step 3: pass edgelist to draw_networkx_edges

I stumbled on this from a [different SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631815/514874).

old broken link: http://networkx.lanl.gov/examples/drawing/weighted_graph.html

Comment: The example link is broken